# How to introduce the play on stage

Tags: sentence-construction

An annoucer has given a brief description of the play on stage and then announced that the play was to start. How to write that announcement grandiosity. "So... Here it is...." Is a correct announcement?

Comment: For what it's worth, if you really want to be grandiloquent, you would *proclaim* something rather than merely *announce* it …

Answer (score 1):

This announcement in grand style is customarily done with the words "And now…" followed by the name of the play, like this:

> And now…*Romeo and Juliet.*

The [M.C.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_ceremonies) then walks off the stage and the curtain opens.

The name of a performer or musical group can take the place of the name of the play, when introducing other types of performances.